# single Windows 7-64 lost access to public shares on NAS "element not found"

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

The NAS is otherwise reachable from the client: web interface, ping - works fine. I map the shares via IP and it works fine with other win7-64 clients in the network. I can also map other local fileservers.
The machine had another quirk: it would ask for credentials when connecting to a public share. Empty credentials where no go but entering mumbojumbo worked. Now I can't even list shares with `\\ip`

Anything better than reinstalling windows?

Comment: So system restore right? The only candidate was the oldest one. Restore failed (AV?) and it wrote over the desired system restore to create a new one to undo system restore. oh dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAS had a user with the same name but different password - windows always tried to authenticate with your user first. It doesn't matter if you map it with another user - it still won't work, at least in my case.